# Postgresql database connection with sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using psql not pgadmin for interacting with sequelize, so while running `sequelize db:migrate` error shows `ERROR: Error reading "config/database.js". Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'USER' of undefined` .
I think there is problem in my config file as i am just starting out,below is my config file :-

```
APP_KEY=
APP_URL=http://localhost:3001/
APP_PORT=3001


DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=hidden
DB_DATABASE=chat_app
```

Comment: using default postgres account btw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, it was in config/database.js DB_HOST was not correctly defined.Also,remember to check tables when you do seqeulize db:migrate.